# How can I access DOM using service in Angular 2?

Tags: jquery, angular, dom

I am thinking to create a feature to hide and show components across the Angular 2 Apps. I have thought about using `*ngIf` or `ngClass` to do so, however, this will be tedious for writing the code. I am now thinking to create a service to access the DOM and capable of showing and hiding components globally.

For example, I have the DOM as follows

```
<my-component-1></my-component-1>
<my-component-2></my-component-2>
<my-component-3></my-component-3>
<my-component-4></my-component-4>
```

I would like to have a function of service as follows

```
DomService.show('my-component-1')
```

Is it possible to do so using native angular 2 without using the pure javascript or jQuery?

Comment: It's the whole point of `angular{Js/2}`. Not to deal with DOM logic in your ... logic (components/services). If you want to manipulate the DOM, do it in a directive. But manipulating the DOM as you want to feels just wrong.

Comment: I am aware of that. But I am thinking of better and more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, angular can.
But, what you try to do is not proper way to do with angularjs. Because, angularjs bind data with DOM.

```
<my-component-1 ng-show="isHidden"></my-component-1>
<my-component-2 ng-show="isHidden"></my-component-2>
<my-component-3 ng-show="isHidden"></my-component-3>
<my-component-4 ng-show="isHidden"></my-component-4>
```

Whenever you change the value of isHidden, it will affect DOM right away.

[Official Document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)